# Adding new Column in Dataframe and updating row values as other columns name based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns as a, c1, c2, c3 c4.

```
df = 
a.   c1.  c2.  c3.  c4.
P1   1    0    0    0
P2   0    0    0    1
P3   1    0    0    0
P4   0    1    0    0
```

On above df, I want to do following operations:
Add a new column main, whose value will be the name of column which contain value 1 for a particular row.
For eg: 1st row will have value 'c1' in its main column, similarly second row will have c4.

The resulting df will look like below:

```
df = 
    a.   c1.  c2.  c3.  c4. main
    P1   1    0    0    0   c1
    P2   0    0    0    1   c4
    P3   1    0    0    0   c1
    P4   0    1    0    0   c2
```

I am new to python and dataframes. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication:

If `a` is first colum omit it by indexing:

```
df['main'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:])
#if possible multiple 1 per row
#df['main'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:] + ',').str.rstrip(',')
print (df)
    a  c1  c2  c3  c4 main
0  P1   1   0   0   0   c1
1  P2   0   0   0   1   c4
2  P3   1   0   0   0   c1
3  P4   0   1   0   0   c2
```

If `a` is index:

```
df['main'] = df.dot(df.columns)
#if possible multiple 1 per row
#df['main'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
print (df)
    c1  c2  c3  c4 main
a                      
P1   1   0   0   0   c1
P2   0   0   0   1   c4
P3   1   0   0   0   c1
P4   0   1   0   0   c2
```